# How do I set up Pushover service to tell me when my Pi is shutting down or starting up?

Tags: boot

I would like to setup my Raspberry Pi to tell me when it is up or down via the curl API of [Pushover](https://pushover.net/) service.
What are the steps to do this?

This came up while I was reading [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1508/how-do-i-access-the-distributions-name-on-the-command-line) question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A lot of distributions, including Arch and Debian/Raspbian, use initscripts to initialise the system, and you can use them to run arbitrary commands. You need to install a script similar to the following in `/etc/init.d`.

```
#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/pushover
#

# Some things that run always
touch /var/lock/pushover

TOKEN=
USER=

DIST=`cat /etc/os-release | perl -n -e '/^NAME=\"([a-zA-Z ]*)\"$/ && print "$1\n"'`

echo $TOKEN
echo $USER
echo $DIST

# Carry out specific functions when asked to by the system
case "$1" in
  start)
echo "Starting script pushover "
curl -s \
  --data-urlencode "token=$TOKEN" \
  --data-urlencode "user=$USER" \
  --data-urlencode "message=Raspberry Pi ($DIST) is starting." \
  https://api.pushover.net/1/messages
;;
  stop)
echo "Stopping script pushover"
curl -s \
  --data-urlencode "token=$TOKEN" \
  --data-urlencode "user=$USER" \
  --data-urlencode "message=Raspberry Pi ($DIST) is stopping." \
  https://api.pushover.net/1/messages
;;
  *)
echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/pushover {start|stop}"
exit 1
;;
esac

exit 0
```

You should register with the [Pushover](https://pushover.net/) service and enter your app token in the `TOKEN` variable and your user key in the `USER` variable.

Test it in your home directory first, then move it to `/etc/init.d/pushover`. You should ensure it is runnable and owned by root.

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/pushover
sudo chown root:root /etc/init.d/pushover
```

#### References

1. [How do I load a module at boot time?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/761/86)
2. [How do I access the distribution's name on the command line?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/1508/86)
3. [Pushover](https://pushover.net/)